# Initializing tuples in ILOG OPL imported form a MS Access Database using .NET

Tags: .net, ms-access, opl

I am connecting an MS Access database to an OPL model using the .NET solution presented here:

https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/OPL-.net-custom-data-source

This works fine and I am getting all the Data out of my Database via SQL. However I am struggling to initialize the tuples. 
My SQL statements look as following:

```
PName SELECT tblProdukte.PName FROM tblProdukte;
tName SELECT tblMaP.tName FROM tblMaP;
Demands SELECT tblProdukte.PName, tblMaP.tName, tblDemand.demDemand
FROM tblProdukte INNER JOIN (tblMaP INNER JOIN tblDemand ON tblMaP.tID = 
tblDemand.demTID) ON tblProdukte.pID = tblDemand.demPID
WHERE (((tblMaP.tName)>0));
```

In the .mod file I am calling the data as following:

```
{string} PName =...;
{int} tName =...;
tuple DemandType{
string PName;
int tName; 
int demDemand;
};
{DemandType} Demands=...;
```

This solution works. But what I actually want to implement is something like

`float Demands [PName][tName] =...;`

I have tried several different approaches including the oil Example and the Transportation Problem provided by IBM. 
How can I achieve the indexing in this exact way?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have something working that gets the desired data, one option is to just transform this data. For example, you could write:

```
float DemandsAsTable[p in PName][t in tName] = sum(d in Demands : d.PName == p && d.tName == t) d.demDemand;
```

(note that each sum will sum exactly one term).